# How to upload image to aws s3 using react and django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redux, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload image to aws s3 using react and drf. I am following this  [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python/) . I am getting error mentioning Request failed with status code 400.

as they have suggested in the link first I created signed url from backend.

```
urlpatterns = [ 
   path('api/create-permission/aws-s3/', SignS3Upload.as_view(), name='aws-s3'),    
]

import os
import boto3
import mimetypes
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

class SignS3Upload(APIView):
    # authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get(self, request):
        s3_bucket = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
        file_name = request.GET['image_name']
        file_type = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0]
        presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
            Bucket=s3_bucket,
            Key=file_name,
            Fields={"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
            Conditions=[
                {"acl": "public-read"},
                {"Content-Type": file_type}
            ],
            ExpiresIn=3600
        )

        data = {
            "signed_url": presigned_post,
            'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (s3_bucket, file_name)
        }
        return Response(data)
```

In frontend I am using React and Redux. here how I am sending request from frontend

```
export const getSignedRequest = (image) => (dispatch, getState) => {

    const image_name = image.name

    axios.get('https://my-site.herokuapp.com/api/blog/api/create-permission/aws-s3/', { params: { image_name } })
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PARTICULAR_BLOG_IMG_UPLOAD,
                payload: res.data
            });


            var postData = new FormData();
            for (key in res.data.fields) {
                postData.append(key, res.data.fields[key]);
            }
            postData.append('file', image_name);

            return axios.post(res.data.url, postData);
        })
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_PARTICULAR_BLOG_IMG_UPLOAD_AWS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });

};
```

I received the response from first axios request in frontend like below

```
signed_url: {
  url: 'https://my-site.s3.amazonaws.com/',
  fields: {
    acl: 'public-read',
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg',
    AWSAccessKeyId: 'xxx_access_id_xxxx',
    policy: 'xxx_policy_xxx',
    signature: 'xxx_signature_xxx'
  }
},
url: 'https://my-site.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg'
```

},

here is settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem. Here is fix I got for you.

**your backend django code should look like this.**

```
import boto3

def create_presigned_url(
    object_name,
    object_type,
    bucket_name=settings.BUCKET_NAME,
    expiration=3600
):


    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region_name=settings.AWS_REGION_NAME,
    )

        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            'put_object',
            {
                'Bucket': bucket_name,
                'Key': object_name,
                'ACL': 'public-read',
                'ContentType': object_type
            },
            ExpiresIn=expiration,
        )
    
    return {
        "signedRequest": response,
        'url': f'https://{bucket_name}.s3.{settings.AWS_REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com/{object_name}'
    }
```

object name and the object type is the file name and file type contained in your request object.

**The code at your frontend should be like this**

```
import axios from "axios";

const fileHandler = (file) => {
    let response = await getSignedUrl({
      fileName: file.name,
      fileType: file.type,
    });
    let { signedRequest, url } = response.data || {};

    // fileType in the headers for the upload
    let options = { headers: { "Content-Type": file.type } };

    let instance = axios.create();
    instance.put(signedRequest, file, options);
}
```

The **url** key from the response object is your image url after sending a put request to signedRequest

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below library for the uploading image that will

```
https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html
```

Comment: i am using that only, I have edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: Upon console.log(err) it is only showing Request failed with status code 400. Can you please tell me where i can found detail error? Please bear with me, fairly new to programming :)

Comment: you can click on the network their you can open the response

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>908A1A8D2F31C9B9</RequestId><HostId>Yg9fQE/myYkfEEc+kAppSWEIVU2WTsZNUGQZFJgXHUwIolndm5fp0SYbcgi7hjk5RUn2/oWDFj0=</HostId></Error>

Comment: its from aws s3,

Comment: Any suggestion how to fix this?